# Rounding labels of raster values in QGIS 3.8

Tags: raster, qgis-3, labeling

In QGIS 3.4 raster values were in label form rounded to 2 decimal places regardless of exact values of the given raster. Is there a possibility to reduce labelling of raster values in QGIS 3.8 to 2 decimal places regardless of exact values as in QGIS 3.4 ?

[image: labelling possibilities in QGIS 3.4]

[image: labelling possibilities in QGIS 3.8]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there is a simple way of doing this through the interface but we could accomplish this with a bit of Python. The code below stores the value and colour of the raster's symbology properties and rounds the value to 2 decimal places (you can change the value if you want) which it stores as the new label. Then it reapplies the updated properties

---

1. So first select your layer from the *Layers Panel* to set it as the active layer:

   [image: Raster with long labels]

---

2. Then enter the following code in the *Python Console* (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring it up):

   ```
   rlayer = iface.activeLayer()
   fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
   fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
   fcn.setClassificationMode(QgsColorRampShader.Continuous)
   lst = []
   for x, y in rlayer.renderer().legendSymbologyItems():
       value = float(x)
       label = str("{0:.2f}".format(float(value)))
       lst.append(QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(value, QColor(y.red(), y.green(), y.blue()), label))

   fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
   shader = QgsRasterShader()
   shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
   renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
   rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
   rlayer.triggerRepaint()
   ```

   Result:

   [image: Raster with shortened labels]